# Optical mouse camera conect to RPi3 via serial port

Tags: python, serial, uart

I try to read the optical mouse sensor IC in the RPi3 via the serial port. The idea is base on [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bci7Gi05BNc) but in my case I have the [ADNS-5020](http://datasheet.datasheetarchive.com/originals/library/Datasheet-035/DSA003220.pdf) sensor. I set `enable_uart=1` in `/boot/config.txt` and I can see `serial0` and `ttyS0` in `/dev`. My connections are:

```
Sensor pin -> RPi3 pin
1 (data)   -> pin 15
5 (VDD5)   -> pin 2
6 (GND)    -> pin 6
8 (clocl)  -> pin 23
```

And this is my toy python script:

```
import serial, time

address = '/dev/ttyS0'
baudrate = 9600
timeout = 3 # in sec

ser = serial.Serial(address, baudrate=baudrate, timeout=timeout)

while 1:
    serial_line = ser.read()
    print(serial_line)

ser.close()
```

This script only print `b'\x00`, but need get the matrix of the image. 
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know what you followed, because I clicked on the link and got an annoying video. Possibly because the pins you are using have nothing to do with the serial port.